# How many LinkedIn connections would I need to be 2nd degree with everyone

Tags: statistics

A mental experiment,

If I would want to be a 2nd degree connection (only 1 person in between me and another one) with everyone on LinkedIn, how many connections would I need to have?

I found these number:

- 722 million users in total (https://news.linkedin.com/about-us#Statistics)
- Every user has 400 connections on average (https://techjury.net/blog/linkedin-statistics/)

My reasoning, if all these people would have a unique network (all 400 connections are different), it would be like this:

- 722 000 000 / 400 = 1.8 million connections

Now, I guess majority of users will have a good amount of overlap, so in reality the number would be higher.

Comment: Are you asking about the worst-case scenario, or rather about an expected number in some random model?

Comment: I'm interested in a somewhat realistic number. I assume it won't be possible with some assumptions (how would one quantify the overlap between connections of different people?)

As I'm a product manager, I'm always interested in applications. If such a model could be fed with real data, it might be awesome to determine your coverage of a certain industry/country/profession! Great for the goal-setting networker.